# TypingError when using numpy.stack() with numba njit

Tags: python, numba

The original issue is connected to using `np.linspace` with arrays as start and stop parameters, though right now I'm having issues with the workaround I came up with.

Take the following:

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np

@njit
def f1():
  start = np.array([0.1, 1.0], np.float32)
  stop = np.array([1.0, 10.0], np.float32)
  return np.linspace(start, stop, 10)

f1()
```

This will raise an error, because [though documented as supporting "only the 3-argument form"](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html) of `linspace`, what they actually mean is "the 3-argument form with scalar values for start and stop".

So I came up with the folloing workaround:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import njit

@njit
def f2():
  start = np.array([0.1, 1.0], np.float32)
  stop = np.array([1.0, 10.0], np.float32)
  pts_0 = np.linspace(start[0], stop[0], 10).astype(np.float32) # works
  pts_1 = np.linspace(start[1], stop[1], 10).astype(np.float32) # works
  return np.stack([pts_0, pts_1]).T                             # error
```

which raises this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypingError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\Users\X\Desktop\X\data_analysis.ipynb Cell 46' in <cell line: 18>()
     15   pts_1 = np.linspace(start[1], stop[1], 10).astype(np.float32)
     16   return np.stack([pts_0, pts_1]).T
---> 18 r = f2()

File c:\Users\X\miniconda3\envs\X\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:468, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args(self, *args, **kws)
    464         msg = (f"{str(e).rstrip()} \n\nThis error may have been caused "
    465                f"by the following argument(s):\n{args_str}\n")
    466         e.patch_message(msg)
--> 468     error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
    469 except errors.UnsupportedError as e:
    470     # Something unsupported is present in the user code, add help info
    471     error_rewrite(e, 'unsupported_error')

File c:\Users\X\miniconda3\envs\X\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py:409, in _DispatcherBase._compile_for_args.<locals>.error_rewrite(e, issue_type)
    407     raise e
    408 else:
--> 409     raise e.with_traceback(None)

TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<function stack at 0x00000186F280CAF0>) found for signature:
 
 >>> stack(list(array(float32, 1d, C))<iv=None>)
```

Again, according to the [documentation](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html), `np.stack` is supported (no side-commens on this one either).

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`np.stack` is supported but it **expect a tuple** instead of a list so far. Here is a fixed code:

```
@njit
def f2():
  start = np.array([0.1, 1.0], np.float32)
  stop = np.array([1.0, 10.0], np.float32)
  pts_0 = np.linspace(start[0], stop[0], 10).astype(np.float32) # works
  pts_1 = np.linspace(start[1], stop[1], 10).astype(np.float32) # works
  return np.stack((pts_0, pts_1)).T                             # works
```

By the way, note that `np.stack((pts_0, pts_1)).T` is not very efficient since it creates *temporary arrays* and a non-contiguous view. Since the purpose of using Numba is to speed up codes, consider using basic loops that should be faster here. The same thing applies for `astype(np.float32)`: a loop can cast the values in-place. Memory and allocations are expensive and this is often what make Numpy slower (also the lack of specific-purpose functions). Such things will be slower in the future (for more information, consider reading more about the "*memory wall*") so one need to avoid them.

Here is a significantly faster version with basic loops:

```
@njit
def f2():
    start1, start2 = np.float32(0.1), np.float32(1.0)
    stop1, stop2 = np.float32(1.0), np.float32(10.0)
    steps = 10
    delta = np.float32(1 / (steps - 1))
    res = np.empty((steps, 2), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(steps):
        res[i, 0] = start1 + (stop1 - start1) * (delta * i)
        res[i, 1] = start2 + (stop2 - start2) * (delta * i)
    return res
```

Note that results can be slightly different due to 32-bit FP rounding.

Comment: Thank you for your remark about temporary arrays, I did suspect that would happen, but I am not sure how numpy handles memory under the hood, nor how numba deals with it. How would you solve the `astype(np.float32)` issue? AFAIK I can't feed `linspace` an output vector, nor does the numba version spport the `dtype` kwarg. How do I avoid the unneccessary copy?

Comment: Also, when you mention reading about the "memoy wait", do you have any specific references in mind? Basic googling didn't help, so perhaps I'm lacking the right keywords?

Comment: I put the code I would personally used. It is 4 time faster on my machine. It is more flexible and easier to optimize further (eg. multithreading for bigger array). It is lower level but this is how fast implementation are made in Numba. As for the term, it is "memory wall" and not "memoy wait". You can start with [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random-access_memory#Memory_wall) (it gives few reference about it including research papers).

Comment: Thank you. Incidentally, I ended up implementing a version very similar to the code you suggested (I kept a running "current_sum" and added `delta` at each iteration to avoid the multiplications. Maybe less numerically stable, but it's good enough forwhat I need anyway). I'm now expanding the idea to the rest of my hot code, as even this simple change halved the runtime of my most expensive function. It just feels *so* weird to write naked loops like this in python.