# Python numba can't combine arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numba

When trying to jit a function that combines two numpy arrays

```py
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

@nb.njit
def combine(a: nb.float64[:], b: nb.float64[:]):
    return np.array([a, b])
```

Running the function with float parameters doesn't throw an error, i.e.

```py
>>> combine(1., 2.)
array([1., 2.])
```

But when I try to combine two arrays, I get

```py
>>> combine(np.array([1., 2.]), np.array([3., 4.]))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\Lucas Gruwez\Documents\test.py", line 14, in <module>
    combine(np.array([1., 2.]), np.array([3., 4.]))
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Gruwez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 468, in _compile_for_args
    error_rewrite(e, 'typing')
  File "C:\Users\Lucas Gruwez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\dispatcher.py", line 409, in error_rewrite
    raise e.with_traceback(None)
numba.core.errors.TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
No implementation of function Function(<built-in function array>) found for signature:

 >>> array(list(array(float64, 1d, C))<iv=None>)

There are 4 candidate implementations:
  - Of which 4 did not match due to:
  Overload in function '_OverloadWrapper._build.<locals>.ol_generated': File: numba\core\overload_glue.py: Line 129.
    With argument(s): '(list(array(float64, 1d, C))<iv=None>)':
   Rejected as the implementation raised a specific error:
     TypingError: array(float64, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence
  raised from C:\Users\Lucas Gruwez\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\numba\core\typing\npydecl.py:488

During: resolving callee type: Function(<built-in function array>)
During: typing of call at c:\Users\Lucas Gruwez\Documents\test.py (12)


File "src\test.py", line 12:
def combine(a: nb.float64[:], b: nb.float64[:]):
    return np.array([a, b])
```

Comment: I am fairly new to numba, so the "why this doesn't work" is a bit fuzzy. My best bet is that numba just hasn't implemented this behavior. to get the code you want, I would replace `np.array([a, b])` with `np.stack((a,b))` according to this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72734477/7638401

Comment: Actually, that answer recommends you create a loop rather than using stack due to wasting memory (I believe your current solution has the same problem).

Comment: I can't replicate the issue with Numba 0.56.4. Your error suggests you are trying to create an array from a list of arrays, for which a failure would make sense. But you call the function with scalars, which doesn't add up. As if you have a signature like `@nb.njit("float64[:](float64[:], float64[:])")` instead of `@nb.njit("float64[:](float64, float64)")`. Your Python types suggest that, but that's independent of Numba.

Answer (score 2):

Using `np.array([a, b])` to concatenate two numpy arrays is a shortcut which is not allowed due to the strict typing requirements of numba. Numba expects a homogenous sequence like `[0,1,2]` and therefore fails.

> TypingError: array(float64, 1d, C) not allowed in a homogeneous sequence

Instead, only use `np.array()` to create new arrays from basic types like float or int inside numba and use `np.stack` or `np.concatenate` for combining existing arrays.

**For example:**

```
@nb.njit
def combine(a: nb.float64[:], b: nb.float64[:]):
    return np.stack((a, b))

combine(np.array([1., 2.]), np.array([3., 4.]))
```

```
array([[1., 2.],
       [3., 4.]])
```

**Or:**

```
@nb.njit
def combine(a: nb.float64[:], b: nb.float64[:]):
    return np.concatenate((a, b))

combine(np.array([1., 2.]), np.array([3., 4.]))
```

```
array([1., 2., 3., 4.])
```

**PS**
Due to the static typing, once compile with `np.float[:]` arrays as dtype, you should not call the function with `np.float64` scalars. Likewise, calling `np.stack((1.,2.))` with scalar numbers will fail. There you will have to use `np.array([1.,2.])` again.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may be helpful, which can be run on both of two single floats or two 1D arrays with the same shapes. For the two arrays, I recommend using indexing to fill the result array, which will work. `isinstance` is experimental feature now, and can be replaced/written with another modules, e.g. `hassattr` or `np.isscaler`, etc, I didn't check if they could be used with numba njit. It was just one solution to show how we could face such problem.

```
@nb.njit  # (["float64[::1](float64, float64)", "float64[:, ::1](float64[::1], float64[::1])"])
def combine(a, b):
    if isinstance(a, float):
        return np.array([a, b])
    else:
        arr = np.empty((2, *a.shape))
        arr[0, :] = a
        arr[1, :] = b
        return arr
```